# My PC gets stuck while sleeping, on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, sleep, shutdown

While installing Windows updates, I pressed the power button (set to do sleep), but my PC got stuck and I was forced to force shutdown by holding down the power button.
Since then I cannot use sleep; it always makes the PC get stuck.

**I tried many things without luck, like:**

- I did a recovery to my PC to a point before I had this problem.
- Uninstalled and re-installed the last driver for my graphics card. I updated the BIOS.
- I tried the `scannow` command, which couldn't repair this file "Amd64\CNBJ2530.DPB".
- I restored power plans to default with `powercfg –restoredefaultschemes`.

**The clues that I have is that sleep works:**

- Before I enter any Windows account.
- When I stop Windows services with `msconfig` and restart.
- I also have a problem with shutdown, it took so long.

My PC is a HP Envy dv6

Comment: Is it normal for people to set their machine to sleep when they want it to do something?

Comment: i was used to use sleep so didn't think it could make me problems, and i did have a situation where i have to move to another place.

Comment: If you have system corruption you need to fix it.  DISM will repair the compondent store which will allow SFC to repair the damage system file.

Comment: i remembered now that i used DISM but it get stuck at 20%, so i have stoped it, do i have to wait, do it take so long.

Comment: It seems that the last sentence in your question, "My PC is a HP Envy dv6", accidentally got lost when I edited it. Sorry about that. I can edit it back in, if you like, but it's fastest if you do this yourself.

Comment: Ramhound i lanched DISM /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup, and it end with this  Error: 14098

The component store has been corrupted

Comment: @habibhassani: Follow [this](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/26512-dism-fixing-component-store-corruption-windows-8-a.html) tutorial.